# TestComplete import testscenario from Selenium

Tags: selenium, testcomplete

Maybe this sounds ridicilous, but still, is there somekind of way to convert/import/hack selenium test scenario to get work on TestComplete?
I ask this, because my boss asked me to find a way, we are using Selenium, but our customer want us to give him TestComplete scripts, so we dont want to buy licence for 1 customer and i havent find any yet and belive there is no... maybe im missing something? Thanks you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct ways to convert Selenium tests to TestComplete as these tools use different principles. Selenium works with web pages "from inside" (programmatically) while TestComplete does this "outside" by simulating user actions: it sends mouse clicks and key presses to the browser.

I think that it is possible to invoke Selenium tests from TestComplete, but you will not have any results in TestComplete and you will be unable to modify tests in it.

BTW, you can [request a free 30-days trial](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing/sign-up/) if a month is enough for you to convert the tests.